# special characters with Net::Twitter::Lite

Tags: html, perl, twitter, unicode

I try to send characters like ü, ä, ß, à and so on to twitter. If I use unicode characters in my scripts they come out wrong in twitter. If I use HTML (which is possible in twitter's web-interface and which used to work previously) I see now &#252; rather than "ü" in the post. Is there a parameter or something that I have to set? Some call to encode/decode? I am using:

`use Net::Twitter::Lite::WithAPIv1_1;`

Comment: “they come out wrong in twitter”—What does this mean? Could you show an explicit example? Also, are you passing unicode strings to the module, or did you encode them before?

Comment: Don't know if it's related, but I found at least one encoding-related problem when trying out the module. See https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=87672

Comment: I gave up the HTML attempt and rewrote my whole code to use unicode. Then I loaded `Encode` and called `$to_twitter = decode("utf-8", $to_twitter);`. This works.

Answer (score 1):

I find myself checking out the test suite of perl modules quite often as it is a good source for examples.

> Net::Twitter expects decoded characters, not encoded bytes So, sending
>   encoded utf8 to Net::Twitter will result in double encoded data.

Source: https://metacpan.org/source/MMIMS/Net-Twitter-Lite-0.12006/t/unicode.t

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
use encoding 'utf8';
```

at the begining of your script. sometimes this is the solution of many utf8 problems.